# Tuples subtraction in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have n-dimensional array with tuples as elements. I want to subtract a tuple from that array & return an array.

```
import numpy as np
x=5
y=5
z=3
# Create an empty array of size 10x8x4
array_slots = np.empty((x, y, z), dtype=object)
array_slots_end = np.empty((x, y, z), dtype=object)

# Iterate over the indices and assign tuples
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        for k in range(z):
            array_slots[i, j, k] = (i, j, k)
```

Create another array from the above array

```
filtered_array = np.concatenate((array_slots[0,:,:],array_slots[:,0,:]),axis=0)

# Filtered_away method creates duplicate entries, hence dropping them.
array_slots_end = DataFrame(filtered_array).drop_duplicates().values
```

Finally trying to do a subtraction:

```
np.subtract(array_slots[0],array_slots_end[0,0])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

However, when I run directly the array it works. And that's what I want as my output.

```
np.subtract([[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
       [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
       [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2)],
       [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2)],
       [(0, 4, 0), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 2)]],(0, 0, 0))

array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 1],
        [0, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 1],
        [0, 3, 2]],

       [[0, 4, 0],
        [0, 4, 1],
        [0, 4, 2]]])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I have n-dimensional array with tuples as elements" - that is a really bad choice of data structure. You're losing like 90% of the benefit of using NumPy and making everything way more awkward for yourself. Plus, tuples don't support subtraction in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for your note. Would have appreciated some suggestions along side the criticism.

Comment: Instead of a `5,5,3` array of 3-tuples, use a `5,5,3,3` array of numbers.

Comment: The criticism points to the best suggestion: instead of storing tuples in your numpy array, add a dimension to the array that allows you to store the data as individual values. Is there are reason you absolutely *must* store your data as tuples?

Comment: To subtract tuples, use `tuple(a - b for a, b in zip(tuple1, tuple2))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I thought of adding more dimensions, but doing subsequent calculations were getting complex. It's actually a 3-d space where each space slot has got multiple variables. So this helped me visualize things better.
One question: any idea why it worked when I directly passed the same array values with tuples & not when I passed it through the variable array_slot[0]?

Answer (score 0):

In the 'direct' case, you provide a list, not an array

```
   np.subtract([[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
   [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
   [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2)],
   [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2)],
   [(0, 4, 0), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 2)]],(0, 0, 0))
```

`np.subtract` makes both arguments arrays, and then does the subtraction

Look at what you get with np.array of that list

```
In [52]: np.array([[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 4, 0), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 2)]]).shape
Out[52]: (5, 3, 3)
```

That's a 3d int dtype array, not your object dtype with tuples.

It's a good illustration of why, at least for calculation purposes, the numeric arrays are best.

It can't do math on tuples.  Tuples are python objects, like lists, and can only do addition, which is defined as join, and multiply, which is replicate.  That is basic Python.

To make the array of tuples, you had use a very round about method, making the array of None, and filling each element separately, with a new tuple object.  Manipulating those tuples will be equally tedious.

```
In [53]: np.array([[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2)],
    ...:        [(0, 4, 0), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 2)]])
Out[53]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 1],
        [0, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 1],
        [0, 3, 2]],

       [[0, 4, 0],
        [0, 4, 1],
        [0, 4, 2]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In the direct case, even if you convert it to an array, the np.subtract still works. `np.subtract(np.array([[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
       [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
       [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2)],
       [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2)],
       [(0, 4, 0), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 2)]]),(0, 0, 0))`
I understand it's not optimal data structure, but my focus is more on some calculation which in more than 3-d is getting complicated. Hence I was trying to understand why direct method works, but not other way.

Comment: Keep in mind that the only way you get the array of tuples is with that special `np.empty(... object)` construction.  Anything else starting with a list, even a list with nested tuples, will actually produce a numeric array.